# What video encoder services do you use with s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, video-encoding

We were using FFmpeg which is free. And when a bug occurred that broke the system, a previous developer installed PandaStream.

My question is, what do you recommend for quality video encoders?

Is it best to stick with ffmpeg and keep it free, or does a small website really need a heavy duty service like Panda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FFmpeg and MEncoder are both good quality FOSS encoders.

If you've got problems with the encoding (re: your bug) at might be worth having a look at their configuration, perhaps even the output codec and working it through that way. It might help if you have a local mirror of your remote system so you can test various configurations quicker than if you were running it on the remote server.

I would be quite surprised if Panda weren't using a tool like mencoder or ffmpeg to do their encodes.

The obvious advantage of a third service (especially for something like video encoding) is it takes a whole load of the heat off your server. Encoding video is a seriously heavy task.

That said, with the prices Panda charge, you could easily build a little render farm using a couple of VPS machines

Edit: Panda even post [their ffmpeg config](http://pandastream.com/docs/encoding_profiles#ffmpeg) so it might be an idea to just nab one of theirs.